# Redux reducer - удалить элемент с store

Tags: reactjs, redux

Добрый день, есть 2 кейса `addToFolder` и `removeFromFolder`.
Не могу дописать код что-бы с сессии удаляло элемент. Через `addToFolder` добавляет. Может кто помочь?)

```
import update from 'immutability-helper';
import _ from 'lodash';

import { toggleSideBar, rebaseData, addToFolder, removeFromFolder } from '../config/actionEvents';

const defaultState = {
    isSidebar: false,
    items: [],
    models: [],
    selectedItems: [],
    selectedModels: []
};

export default (state = defaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case toggleSideBar:
        return update(state, {isSidebar: {$set: action.state.isSidebar}});
    case rebaseData:
        return update(state, {[action.state.key]: {$set: action.state.value}});
    case addToFolder:
        if (action.state.type === 'item') {
            return update(state, {selectedItems: {$push: [action.state.element]}});
        } else if (action.state.type === 'model') {
            return update(state, {selectedModels: {$push: [action.state.element]}});
        }
    case removeFromFolder:
        if (action.state.type === 'item') {
            const itemId = action.data;
            return _.filter(item => item.id !== itemId);
        } else if (action.state.type === 'model') {
            const modelId = action.data;
            return _.filter(model => model.id !== modelId);
        }

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Зачем вам `lodash`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понял так вы решите вашу задачу:

```
case removeFromFolder:
    if (action.state.type === 'item') {
        const itemId = action.data;
        return {...state, items: state.items.filter(item => item.id !== itemId)}
    } else if (action.state.type === 'model') {
        const modelId = action.data;
        return {...state, models: state.models.filter(model => model.id !== modelId)}
    }
```